# How to put legend outside the plot with pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

How is it possible to put legend outside the plot?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = {'Test1': {1: 21867186, 4: 20145576, 10: 18018537},
    'Test2': {1: 23256313, 4: 21668216, 10: 19795367}}

d = pd.DataFrame(a).T
#print d

f = plt.figure()

plt.title('Title here!', color='black')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
d.plot(kind='bar', ax=f.gca())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Actually it's not a complete duplicate...the question is asking specifically for Pandas. The response below shows how to assign an axis to a plot function call from `pandas.DataFrame.plot` which makes it possible to apply the `matplotlib.pyplot` refinements.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a duplicate and it's annoying that it's marked as such.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate, as it is for Pandas `.plot`. The solution is outlined below thanks to @matt_harrison, but to summarize:  where you have `d.plot(kind='bar', ax=f.gca())`, change this to `d.plot(kind='bar', ax=f.gca()).legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))`

Comment: Check this folks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot  It has really good discussion/answers and this question is *pretty much* a duplicate of that one, if you know minimal pandas/matplotlib.

Answer (score 142):

I think  you need to call `plot` before you add the calling `legend`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = {'Test1': {1: 21867186, 4: 20145576, 10: 18018537},
    'Test2': {1: 23256313, 4: 21668216, 10: 19795367}}

d = pd.DataFrame(a).T
#print d

f = plt.figure()

plt.title('Title here!', color='black')
d.plot(kind='bar', ax=f.gca())
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

----- Panda solution
If you are using pandas Dataframe.plot

```
dataframe_var.plot.bar().legend(loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5));
```

Comment: However, half of the legend is now not in picture? How is it possible to fix it?

Comment: It's really a separate question, but you could try `f.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)`.

Comment: If you just want to move the legend, you can take advantage of the fact that ``.plot`` returns a matplotlib axis and add ``.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))`` to the end of your plot line of code

Comment: The comment by @mattharrison should be the answer.

Comment: I don't think it is a separate question, the point is to move the legend, I don't see why would the legend suddenly be half-cut after it has been moved.

Comment: Not working for me the legend is outside of the plot even with the `bbox_to_anchor` stuff. Note there are some really good discussions of this issue at the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot

Answer (score 15):

I am able to place the legend outside the chart with the following snippet based on OP's question:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = {'Test1': {1: 21867186, 4: 20145576, 10: 18018537},
    'Test2': {1: 23256313, 4: 21668216, 10: 19795367}}

df = pd.DataFrame(a).T

ax = df.plot.bar()
ax.set_title("Title here!",color='black')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0))
ax.plot()
```

How it appears in my notebook:
[image]

You can then modify the anchor values to adjust its placement as needed. The anchor point would be the bottom left hand corner of this chart.

Comment: thanks @CodeBender! That simple answer is what I needed!!

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5)) #here is the magic
```

Comment: This is the same as the answer from @Phil six years prior.

Answer (score 3):

### **I felt more easy to use this one, any feedback appreciated**

```
df.plot(kind='area')
plt.legend(loc=(1.01,.35)) #here I tried to keep it outside middle right
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the legend outside of the plot in matplotlib, you can use the bbox_to_anchor papameter along with the loc parameter of the legend function, here's how you can modify your code to achieve that:

```
df3.iloc[0:30].plot.area(alpha=0.4)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.show()
```